# c++ hide terminal with GTKMM gui apps

Tags: c++11, unix, gtkmm3

I've been looking around on the cplusplus forum and here on stackoverflow, but I have not been able to find an answer. All I find is Windows stuff or people working with IDE'S that do the work for them.

I am creating an application with c++ and GTKMM and nothing else, I just have a texteditor and a compiler that I control with my terminal (I adress this because a lot of people always talk about IDE'S and stuff) on UNIX based computers.

When I run my application (./application) I always see my terminal along with my gui application and I would like to hide the terminal. How would I achieve this?

Thanks in prior :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out it differs from operation system. I've written out what I've found on [my website](https://extra.freetimedev.com/index.php?category=tutorials&subject=app-bundle), so check it out if you want to create a mac application.